# Does the CPU cares about the DPL and the RPL when executing some instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

I believe that the CPU looks at the CPL when executing privileged instructions. If the CPL is 0 (kernel mode) then the CPU can execute the privileged instructions, and if the CPL is 3 (user mode), then the CPU can't execute the privileged instructions (it can only execute user mode instructions in this case).

Also there are some instructions like `IN` and `OUT` where the CPU looks at the CPL and the IOPL and the I/O Permission Bitmap in the TSS structure in order to see if it can execute them.

But does the CPU cares about the DPL and the RPL when executing some instructions? or are the the DPL and the RPL have no role at all when execution instructions, and they only matter when using memory segmentation?

Comment: They affect the behavior of far call and far ret, for example. I believe they also affect the behavior of all memory access instructions.

Comment: Most of the instructions that have a selector operand check the DPL/RPL of the selector, eg. MOV *Sreg*, POP *Sreg*, RETF, IRET, LAR, LSL, VERR, VERW.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment: The DPL of a data segment descriptor indicates the highest CPL or RPL that can access the segment. So a segment with a DPL of 0 cannot be accessed from ring 3 or using a segment selector with RPL=3. See section 5.5 of the Intel SDM.

Comment: Side note - on many processors, [speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) doesn't check privilege, leading to potential exploits as noted at the end of the linked to wiki article.